# Check Date between two date columns from two dates SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I want check date between two dates the record is available or not

Here is the table:

**Table1**:

```
S.No    StartDate         EndDate
-------------------------------------
1.      15/10/2018        20/10/2018
2.      10/10/2018        13/10/2018
3.      21/10/2018        25/10/2018
```

I need the Output

**Five Conditions:**

1. within the date E.g. 17/10/2018 - 19/10/2018

   ```
   S.No    StartDate         EndDate
   -------------------------------------
    1      15/10/2018        20/10/2018
   ```
2. out of the date E.g. 14/10/2018 - 21/10/2018

   ```
   S.No    StartDate         EndDate
   -------------------------------------
    1      15/10/2018        20/10/2018
    3      21/10/2018        25/10/2018
   ```
3. Previous from start date E.g. 13/10/2018 - 16/10/2018

   ```
   S.No    StartDate         EndDate
   -------------------------------------
    1      15/10/2018        20/10/2018
    2      10/10/2018        13/10/2018
   ```
4. Next from start date E.g. 17/10/2018 - 20/10/2018

   ```
   S.No    StartDate         EndDate
   -------------------------------------
     1      15/10/2018        20/10/2018
   ```
5. another date E.g. 17/11/2018 - 21/11/2018

   ```
   No records
   ```

Here is my idea and my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, '15/10/2018', 103) BETWEEN StartDate 
                                          AND EndDate 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, '20/10/2018', 103) BETWEEN StartDate  
                                             AND EndDate
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's wrong with your current attempt? Why do you use convert, are your dates not in a date(time(2)) datatype? If so, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to find **date range intersections**. But your query finds just date ranges that completely includes your date range parameter.
To find the date range intersections you need to change your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, '14/10/2018', 103) <=  EndDate 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, '21/10/2018', 103) >= StartDate
```

if you need all five conditions in a single query without duplicates you can combine it by `OR`:

```
...
WHERE 
   CONVERT(DATE, '14/10/2018', 103) <=  EndDate 
   AND CONVERT(DATE, '21/10/2018', 103) >= StartDate 
OR
   CONVERT(DATE, '17/10/2018', 103) <=  EndDate 
   AND CONVERT(DATE, '19/10/2018', 103) >= StartDate 
...
```

If you want all five conditions with duplicates you can use `union all`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, '14/10/2018', 103) <=  EndDate 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, '21/10/2018', 103) >= StartDate 

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, '17/10/2018', 103) <=  EndDate 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, '19/10/2018', 103) >= StartDate 
...
```

Comment: thanks, i need to check 5 out puts in a single query

Comment: You can combine that condition by `OR` with remaining parameters. Is it what you want?